# Rails persisting table data after MySQL truncate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I truncated 2 tables in my database in MySQL (for a Rails project) so that I could repopulated it with test data. But for some reason the application is still counting how many entries there used to be (250), even though there is only 9 entries now.

I even went into the ruby console using (ruby script/rails console), then truncated using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE bars;")
```

but that didn't do anything different then running the query through MySQL. I am pretty confused, the only thing I can think of doing is restarting the server. I am just wondering if there is maybe another way to do this without having to reboot everything.

Printing the search to the logger I can see that the results for the bars are a bunch of nil values for where there used to be a bar_profile, but I have truncated the tables that referenced bars or bar_profiles.

So I don't get why it would just be returning what the results would have been before the tables were truncated. Except now now instead of returning actual results they are just nil.

Comment: How are you doing your counting?

Comment: By running a search query through the Bar model, then counting the results.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Something might be cached.